# kotlin declaring Object within sealed class and initialized

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

```
sealed class StockLabel : Label() {
  object OutOfStockLabel : StockLabel()
}
```

I know sealed class in kotlin is implicitly abstract and we will get compile error if doing so. But I saw the usage of the code above, the 'OutOfStockLabel' is declared within the 'StockLabel' sealed class also with 'StockLabel()', the 'StockLabel()' I think should be the type for 'OutOfStockLabel' but is it here for initialization or?

Need some help to understand the code case here.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you ask. `OutOfStockLabel` is simply a subtype of `StockLabel` and it is defined inside it just to use it as a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the syntax looks similar, this code:

```
object OutOfStockLabel : StockLabel()
```

is the syntax for defining a class, not creating an instance of the abstract class. You are declaring a subclass (an `object` in this case) whose primary constructor (which is implicit for an `object`) calls the abstract class's constructor. This is permitted for abstract classes. If you couldn't, it would be impossible to create any subclasses of an abstract class.